# Chrome extension does not work to inject a button into pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing the minimum code to inject a button on any page but it keeps reporting the error "Uncaught TypeError: chrome.action.triggerAction is not a function".

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Button Injector",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
  }
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="inject-btn">Inject Button</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: addBtnToPage,
    });
  });

  function addBtnToPage() {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerText = 'Injected Button';
    document.body.insertBefore(btn, document.body.firstChild);
  }
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById('inject-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("TESTE");
    chrome.action.triggerAction();
  });
```

Comment: There's indeed no such thing as triggerAction. Remove your background.js from disk and from manifest.json, move addBtnToPage and executeScript into click listener in the popup, see also [these examples](/a/67227376).